# Fill RadGridView dynamically

Tags: telerik, datasource, radgridview

I am using RadControls for WinForms 2011 Q3

The datasource for a RadGridView is dynamically generated based on users' input/selection 
Everytime when a datasource is generated, I will call SetDatasource2KeyValuesGrid()
What I expect to see is columns generated and values filled in gridview. 
However what I see is columns generated but no value filled even though the number of rows in gridview match the number of items in its datasource(keyValuesList)
I must have missed something simple. Please help. thanks

Edit: 
I create a DataTable from the list keyValueList, and then assign it to DataSource, then it works
Just wonder if there's a better way. thanks

```
private void CreateTableSetDatasource(List<FeedKeyValueOneSet>) keyValueList)
{
    if(keyValueList==null) return;

    var table = new DataTable();
    table.Columns.Add("Check");
    foreach (var feedKeyValueOneSet in keyValueList)
    {
        var oneset = feedKeyValueOneSet.KeyValueOneSet;               
        foreach (var oneKey in oneset)
        {
            table.Columns.Add(oneKey.key);
        }
        break;
    }

    foreach (var feedKeyValueOneSet in keyValueList)
    {
        var oneset = feedKeyValueOneSet.KeyValueOneSet;
        var numOfCol = oneset.Length + 1;
        var obj = new object[numOfCol];
        obj[0] = "false";
        int idx = 1;
        foreach (var oneKey in oneset)
        {
            obj[idx] = oneKey.value;
            idx++;
        }
        table.Rows.Add(obj);
    }
    radGridKeyValues.DataSource = table;
}


private void SetDatasource2KeyValuesGrid()
{
    if (radGridKeyValues.Columns != null) radGridKeyValues.Columns.Clear();
    radGridKeyValues.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
    radGridKeyValues.EnableFiltering = false;
    radGridKeyValues.ShowFilteringRow = false;
    radGridKeyValues.ShowHeaderCellButtons = false;
    radGridKeyValues.AllowDragToGroup = false;
    radGridKeyValues.AllowAddNewRow = false;
    radGridKeyValues.EnableGrouping = false;

    var keyValueList = (List<FeedKeyValueOneSet>)TimeSeries.FeedValuesCache[m_strFeedName + "_KEYVALUES"];
    if(keyValueList==null) return;

    GridViewDataColumn checkBoxColumn = new GridViewCheckBoxColumn("columnState", "columnState");
    checkBoxColumn.HeaderText = string.Empty;
    if (radGridKeyValues.Columns != null) radGridKeyValues.Columns.Add(checkBoxColumn);

    foreach (var feedKeyValueOneSet in keyValueList)
    {
        var oneset = feedKeyValueOneSet.KeyValueOneSet;
        foreach (var oneKey in oneset)
        {
            var textboxCol = new GridViewTextBoxColumn(oneKey.key, oneKey.key);
            textboxCol.Width = 150;
            textboxCol.ReadOnly = true;
            if (radGridKeyValues.Columns != null) radGridKeyValues.Columns.Add(textboxCol);
        }
        break;
    }

    radGridKeyValues.DataSource = keyValueList;
}

public class FeedKeyValueOneSet
{
    public FeedFieldValues[] KeyValueOneSet;
}

public class FeedFieldValues
{
    public string key { get; set; }
    public string value { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I create a DataTable from the list keyValueList, and then assign it to DataSource, then it works 
see code in edit to the question