# Telerik WinForms RadGridView create and fill in runtime

Tags: c#, winforms, gridview, grid, telerik

My question is pretty similar for this

[Fill RadGridView dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12849414/fill-radgridview-dynamically)

but i dont want to create datatable

This is grid view

```
 GridView = new RadGridView
            {
                    AutoSizeRows = true,
                    BeginEditMode = RadGridViewBeginEditMode.BeginEditProgrammatically,
                    Location = new Point(0, 130),
                    Name = "GridView",
                    ShowRowErrors = false,
                    Size = new Size(390, 100),
                    TabIndex = 0,
                    Visible = false
            };
```

This method creates columns in runtime

```
 private List<GridViewTextBoxColumn> InitializeColumns()
    {
        var result = new List<GridViewTextBoxColumn>();

        {
            var columnId = new GridViewTextBoxColumn
                {
                    Name = "RecordID",
                    HeaderText = "ID",
                    FieldName = "RecordID",
                    MaxLength = 50,
                    Width = 50,
                    DataType = typeof(int)
                };
            result.Add(columnId);
        }

        {
            var columnInformation = new GridViewTextBoxColumn
                {
                    Name = "RecordInformation",
                        HeaderText = "Information",
                        FieldName = "RecordInformation",
                        MaxLength = 50,
                        Width = 250,
                        DataType = typeof(string)
                };
            result.Add(columnInformation);
        }

        {
            var columnRowType = new GridViewTextBoxColumn
            {
                Name = "RecordType",
                HeaderText = "Type",
                FieldName = "RecordType",
                MaxLength = 50,
                Width = 250,
                DataType = typeof(string)
            };
            result.Add(columnRowType);
        }

        return result;
    }
```

This class is for grid row

```
internal class OrderTripChangedAlertItem
{
    public int RecordID { get; set; }
    public string RecordInformation { get; set; }
    public string RecordType { get; set; }

    public OrderTripChangedAlertItem(int recordID, string recordInformation, string recordType)
    {
        RecordID = recordID;
        RecordInformation = recordInformation;
        RecordType = recordType;
    }
}
```

So i bind the List to grid view. Columns are displayed fine, but not data shown. There must be one record. What i missed ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the whole code I placed on a Form and this works just fine:

```
    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);

        RadGridView GridView = new RadGridView
        {
            AutoSizeRows = true,
            BeginEditMode = RadGridViewBeginEditMode.BeginEditProgrammatically,
            Location = new Point(0, 130),
            Name = "GridView",
            ShowRowErrors = false,
            Size = new Size(390, 100),
            TabIndex = 0,
            //Visible = false,
            Parent = this
        };

        GridView.Columns.AddRange(InitializeColumns().ToArray());

        List<OrderTripChangedAlertItem> list = new List<OrderTripChangedAlertItem>();
        OrderTripChangedAlertItem item = new OrderTripChangedAlertItem(0, "some info", "some type");
        list.Add(item);
        GridView.DataSource = list;
    }

    private List<GridViewTextBoxColumn> InitializeColumns()
    {
        var result = new List<GridViewTextBoxColumn>();

        {
            var columnId = new GridViewTextBoxColumn
            {
                Name = "RecordID",
                HeaderText = "ID",
                FieldName = "RecordID",
                MaxLength = 50,
                Width = 50,
                DataType = typeof(int)
            };
            result.Add(columnId);
        }

        {
            var columnInformation = new GridViewTextBoxColumn
            {
                Name = "RecordInformation",
                HeaderText = "Information",
                FieldName = "RecordInformation",
                MaxLength = 50,
                Width = 250,
                DataType = typeof(string)
            };
            result.Add(columnInformation);
        }

        {
            var columnRowType = new GridViewTextBoxColumn
            {
                Name = "RecordType",
                HeaderText = "Type",
                FieldName = "RecordType",
                MaxLength = 50,
                Width = 250,
                DataType = typeof(string)
            };
            result.Add(columnRowType);
        }

        return result;
    }

    internal class OrderTripChangedAlertItem
    {
        public int RecordID { get; set; }
        public string RecordInformation { get; set; }
        public string RecordType { get; set; }

        public OrderTripChangedAlertItem(int recordID, string recordInformation, string recordType)
        {
            RecordID = recordID;
            RecordInformation = recordInformation;
            RecordType = recordType;
        }
    }
```